# IIS6 running applications requiring various older versions of .NET framework

Tags: iis-6

I have ASP.NET web services and ASP.NET web application running on .NET framework 1.1 hosted on a Windows Server 2003 IIS 6 machine.

I have a new application requiring on .NET 4. Until I installed ASP.NET framework 4.0, it was working fine.

Now my .NET framework 1.1 applications have failed.

How can you configure an IIS 6 instance to run 2+ applications each respectively requiring different versions of the .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create at least two separate application pools - for two different frameworks.  Then assign each application to run in the appropriate pool.

These links may help too:

http://wiki.onega.net/index.php?title=How_to_run_multiple_versions_of_the_ASP.NET_framework_simultaneously_on_an_IIS6_Server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631874/iis6-application-pools-asp-net-framework

Comment: how to assign frameworks for two different app pools, i did not see any where assigning frame work in create application pool in iis6. i can see this in iis 7

Comment: this info is not sufficient

Comment: sorry, let me clarify.  you just set up separate application pools, you don't specify framework version for app pool.  but in your web application you specify framework version in ASP.NET tab.